# How do I add a list of brand names to data frame or if it does not appear add 'None'?

Tags: python

```
brand_names = ["Tommy Hilfiger", "Tommy Jeans", "Hugo", "Hugo Boss", "Boss", "HUGO", "Lacoste", "lacoste",
               "Adidas",
               "adidas", "Armani", "The North Face", "Paul Smith", "Vivienne Westwood", "Levis", "Kent And Curwen",
               "Nike", "BOSS", "Calvin Klein", "Kent and Curwen",
               "Pretty Green", "Lyle And Scott", "Moschino", "Converse", "Timberland", "Ralph Lauren", "Fred Perry",
               "True Religion",
               "Luke 1977", "Belstaff", "Paul And Shark", "CP Company", "Money Tri Wheel", "Money Sig", "Gant","Versace"]

image = []
title = []
price = []
link = []
shop = []
brand = []


mainline_t_shirt(soup, brand_names)

mainline = pd.DataFrame({
    'Images': image,
    'Titles': title,
    'Prices': price,
    'link': link,
    'Website': 'mainlinemenswear',
    'brand': brand

})

# Image
(code) 63 elements- code working
# Title
(code) 63 elements- code working
# Price
(code) 63 elements- code working
# link
(code) 63 elements- code working
# website
(code) 63 elements- code working

#brand
    **for container5 in title_div:
        for temp in brand_names_in:
            if temp in container5.text:
                print(temp)
                brand.append(temp)
            if temp not in container5.text:
                brand.append("None")**
```

The data frame 'mainline' has 63 rows. The issue is the 'brand' column. Everytime I run this code I get this error

```
   raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

This is because not all the brands(Nike, Adidas etc) are in the container.text. How can I add the string "None" to the row instead of adding the brand?

The code that needs to be changed is in between the two stars.

Comment: Your two `if` conditions are actually one single `if...else`

Comment: The error occurs at this segment "if temp not in container5.text:
                brand.append("None")". If removed it runs ok but I would like to add "None" to the dataframe

Comment: The code in the stars is what needs to be changed

Comment: Do you really mean to add "None" to the row? Not to the column instead? Since "brand" is a column in your dataframe.

Comment: "None" needs to be added to every row in the column "brand" that does not have a brand in the brand_names list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for each `container5`, you're looping over *all* your brands. Out of the 20 or so brands, only one (if any) will be matched with `container5.text`. Every other brand will mismatch and as a result, `brand.append("None")` is executed. In total about 20 × `len(title_div)`. Which makes the `brand` list far too large, with lots of "None"s (which you could see if you `print(brand)` somewhere inside or directly after the loop).

You can use a for-else here:

```
for container5 in title_div:
    for temp in brand_names_in:
        if temp in container5.text:
            brand.append(temp)
            break
    else: # not broken out of the inner for-loop, thus there was no match
        brand.append("None")
```

Comment: Note that your question is not fully clear, and the example code, example input data and expected output are incomplete. The above suggestion is a solution for one problem you are likely to have, but there may be other ones lurking.